# Unity iOS with Firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, firebase, protocol-buffers

I am try to build an iOS application, but when the app is compiling I receive the following error

```
In file included from /Users/babri/Documents/ohmybrand/app/app/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Any.pbobjc.m:13:
In file included from /Users/babri/Documents/ohmybrand/app/app/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers_RuntimeSupport.h:34:
In file included from /Users/babri/Documents/ohmybrand/app/app/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:44:
/Users/babri/Documents/ohmybrand/app/app/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBWellKnownTypes.h:44:10: fatal error: 'google/protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h' file not found
 #import "google/protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I do not see the same error when building for Android. I've checked that the file exist. And Unity generates the project for XCode.

**SOLUTION**

Google has released a new version to fix this error. :)

Comment: on which version was this fixed? did you have to change s.dependency "!ProtoCompiler-gRPCPlugin" in your podspec?

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is removing "google/protobuf/" from every header include.

It could not fix the issue fundamentally, but at least you can build your unity project.